# Highchart not rendering in shiny using 'Highcharter' package

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I'm having problems getting highcharter to work with my shiny app.  What's really weird is that some of the highcharts work and some don't.  It's probably some dumb mistake I'm not catching.  Anyways, here's some code:

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(width = 12,  
               highchartOutput("hc_more.FA",height="500px")
  )
)
server = function(input, output) {

  output$hc_more.FA <- renderHighchart({
      hchart(diamonds$carat)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here's what my app looks like?
[image]

Here's my session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.1.0     highcharter_0.3.0 shiny_0.13.2     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] igraph_1.0.1      Rcpp_0.12.5       magrittr_1.5      munsell_0.4.3     colorspace_1.2-6  viridisLite_0.1.3
 [7] xtable_1.8-2      lattice_0.20-33   R6_2.1.2          plyr_1.8.4        stringr_1.0.0     TTR_0.23-1       
[13] dplyr_0.4.3       tools_3.3.0       xts_0.9-7         parallel_3.3.0    quantmod_0.4-5    grid_3.3.0       
[19] gtable_0.2.0      data.table_1.9.6  DBI_0.4-1         htmltools_0.3.5   assertthat_0.1    digest_0.6.9     
[25] tidyr_0.4.1       purrr_0.2.1       htmlwidgets_0.6   rlist_0.4.6.1     mime_0.4          stringi_1.1.1    
[31] scales_0.4.0      jsonlite_0.9.21   httpuv_1.3.3      chron_2.3-47      zoo_1.7-13
```

Any ideas whats going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that you cannot have a dot in the chart name. Remove the dot and it works.

Comment: That was the problem.  I know shiny doesn't like when you have dot in input/output names, I'll be sure to keep an eye for that in the future.

Comment: Just discovered this thread because I was having the same problem, even though I've been using Highcharts for a year now! (I guess by chance I never included dots in chart names.) Don't really understand why it fails silently though, and why the dots are problematic to begin with?